# error when saving custom user field in a custom Page Layout

Tags: 2013, page-layout, spfield

I have created a custom user field as follows

```
<Field
  ID="{9B49F1A5-7FFB-400B-9B0E-0FC4D6C1417C}"
  Name="AMtalatFieldEditors"
  DisplayName="My Editors"
  Type="UserMulti"
  Mult="TRUE"
  Required="TRUE"
  ShowField="FirstName" 
  StaticName="AMtalatFieldEditors"
  SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3"
  Customization=""
  UserSelectionMode="PeopleOnly"
  UserSelectionScope="0"
  Group="MyGroup"
  ShowInNewForm="TRUE">
</Field>
```

added it to my content type

```
  <FieldRef ID="{9B49F1A5-7FFB-400B-9B0E-0FC4D6C1417C}" Name="AMtalatFieldEditors" DisplayName="My Editors" Required="TRUE" Customization="" ShowInNewForm="TRUE"/>
```

add it to the page layout

```
 <div id="editorsDiv">
            <SharePointWebControls:UserField ID="AMtalatFieldEditors" FieldName="AMtalatFieldEditors" runat="server" />
        </div>
```

I edit a page and change the page layout to the mine and fill out the user field and click on Save. But the value of user field is disappeared and when I click on Check in, it says:
Error: you have to fill out the required property and when I click on "OK" it redirects me to the page to fill the properties. it seems I never can check in my pages.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.... Can anyone help us?

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with the browser HTML5 validation I believe. 
The way to get away is either ensuring to click save button without or before validation fires and other is to amend changes using SP designer.

Comment: Uhm, how could this possibly be an HTML 5 issue?

Comment: Well thats not issue with HTML5, but the behaviour of HTML5 required validation is not addressed properly while saving in SP

Comment: Html5 validation is not involved in any part

Comment: You no need to write for HTML5 validation, it takes places when you have a input tag with required, and in this case the FieldRef has Required="TRUE". If you inspect element you could see required attribute.

Comment: My problem was, there was anothoer required field which was filed out. so it was why I got this error. It was not the user field problem. If you have another field which is required and is empty your value to userfield will not be saved.

Comment: Yes its basic form post operation where if any of HTML5 input field is required and empty it will not post. That may be a part of SP custom user field or any other input fields